# SQL query in rails to group ordered records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Check is a model that has the attributes **product_line_id** and **date**.

I have four instances of the Check model.  They all have different dates.  Two belong to product line 1 and the other two belong to product line 2.

How do I call a query on the Check model to return one check for each product line having the greatest date for for that product line?

Comment: It's not a good idea to name a database column `date`. It's a reserved word in SQL and meaningful to ruby too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with noodl: you shouldn't be using `date` as the column's name.

```
Check.select("id, product_line_id, max(date) as greatest_date").group(:product_line_id)
```

Comment: I had to use max(date) as date.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Check.group(:product_line_id).maximum(:date)
```

Comment: Why does it just return a hash and not the record?

Comment: I guess it's doing that for indexing purposes? I was a little surprised to see it too. If you specify .select('checks.*, max(`date`) as oldest') it should give you both.